# UILabel int count ++ doesn't work

Tags: ios, numbers, int

I'm trying to indefinitely count up a number of taps on a `UILabel`, every time the label is tapped a different string is displayed. However, it stops at 2 taps always using `++` or `+= 1`

```
 -(void)cycleLabelString {
    int taps;
    taps += 1;
    NSLog(@"taps = %d", taps);

    if (taps == 1) {
        self.randomLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%.2f", pagesCount * 0.69];
    } else if (taps == 2) {
        self.randomLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", pagesCount];
    } else if (taps >= 3) {
        NSLog(@" >= 3");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int taps;
```

This initializes a new `taps` each time, and it is initialized to zero by default. You probably want it in a property. Make a private class extension at the top of your .m file like this:

```
@interface YourClassNameHere ()

@property (nonatomic) int taps;

@end
```

And then to use it:

```
-(void)cycleLabelString {
    self.taps += 1;
    NSLog(@"taps = %d", self.taps);

    if (self.taps == 1) {
        self.randomLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%.2f", pagesCount * 0.69];
    } else if (self.taps == 2) {
        self.randomLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", pagesCount];
    } else if (self.taps >= 3) {
        NSLog(@" >= 3");
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't make it a public property.

Comment: Right - hence the private class extension.

Comment: Oops - sorry. I didn't notice the `()`. Never mind :)

Comment: Dont have enough rep to vote up but thanks @ZevEisenberg

Answer (score 0):

is this function getting called everytime the label is tapped? if so, you will need to define taps as a global variable, as it is being reset everytime the label is tapped. try something like:

```
int taps;

-(void)cycleLabelString {
...
```

Comment: Why would you make it a global? Make it an instance variable.